# What's the syntax for filtering out records with certain phrases in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

The json looks like this

```
{
  "company": {
    "type": "SME",
    "name": "Taylor Corps"
  },
  "contact": {
    "tel": "5334234234",
    "name": "Jane Doe"
  },
  "affiliates": {
    "org": "Taylor Corps"
  }
}
```

image I want to `filter` out all the people who has "Taylor" in their `company.name` or `affiliates.org`.

I tried `multi_field` in a `bool filter` doesn't seem working in filter.

Any advice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following query:

```
{
"query": {
    "query_string": {
       "fields": [
          "company.name" , "affiliates.org"
       ], 
       "query": "Taylor"
      }
    }
}
```